# How does one make a fixed fluid table centered with empty space on both sides?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I made a JS fiddle of it working properly in Chrome and Safari :

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWvzB/

But this doesn't work the same way in Firefox. In Firefox, it aligns right.

Anyone know how I can make this work for both Firefox and Chrome? And... also.. IE ?

I hope this doesn't throw anyone off, but to make it work exclusively in FF and **not** chrome, what I do is make the `.sticky` class have a width set to `inherit` . Then it'll work just for FF and Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

**CSS**

```
.sticky
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:31px;
    right:31px;
}
.sticky table
{
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:100%;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.sticky table tr
{
    background:blue;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sticky">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Crazy Fixed Div</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWvzB/34/)**

Comment: No, you are brilliant and you are the reason why I have hope in our future as humanity.

Answer (score 1):

This will cover FireFox

```
.sticky { 
text-align: -webkit-center;    //Chrome
text-align: -moz-center;   //FireFox
text-align: center;  
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 120;  
padding: 0 31px;
width: 100%;    
display: inline-table;
}
```

you can also center with margin auto, as that is probably the preferred way to do it

```
   margin: auto;
```

HERE is basic centering in FireFox;

```
.sticky-container {
 text-align: -moz-center;
 width: 100%;   
 position: fixed;   
}

  .sticky {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
z-index: 120;
```

}

Comment: you should use margin:auto , and NO , you do not have '-moz-center' and -webkit-center' in your jsfiddle

Comment: you only have one line  that says "text-align: center; "

Comment: Why would anyone vote this answer up? Do we give upvotes for untested, non-working answers these days?

Comment: The padding is the cause. It isn't the same in FF.

Comment: both of my answers work in FireFox , I have used them both several times

Comment: @LewsTherin Supposin' it was the padding. And I used, alternatively, margin directly on the table.. how could it apply universally?

Comment: make the container fixed and center the table in the fixed container - I think that was the problem